# Getting C++ calculations to C# program

Tags: c#, methods, c++-cli

I have a C++ project and want to be able to call the functions in C#.

I created a C++ Class Library and referenced this in the C# project. This all works fine. (I understand that the Method definition should only be in the .h file and the method body should be in the .cpp file. For the example I'll write it together.)

```
//Definition in C++
namespace Formularia {
    public ref class functions{
    public:
        long calculateSum(long a, long b){
            return a + b;
        }
    };
}
```

With this I am able to call it in C# as follows:

```
long result = functions.calculateSum(1, 2);
```

I am able to run it like this, however says 'Could not load file or assembly '............' or one of its dependencies'.

---

If I remove the `ref` as follows:

```
namespace Formularia {
    public class functions{
    public:
        functions();
        long calculateSum(long a, long b){
            return a + b;
        }
    };
}
```

In my opinion I should be able to call it like this in C#:

```
functions f = new functions();'
f.    //I do not get the method here, it is unknown
```

---

Another thing I've tried is to just create the methods at Namespace level:

```
//Definition in C++
namespace Formularia {
    static long calculatesum(long a, long b){
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

I cannot make the method public, it expects an identifier. But I can also not call; `Formularia.calculatesum(1, 2)`. Also tried to remove the static here.

---

The solution is probably quite simple, but I'd prefer to call it like a static class in C#. (Like the ref example). Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It appears that you aren't showing your real code, because none of these is legal.  All you want is an example of a static class in C++/CLI?

Comment: Anyway your first example is the closest, but you are missing the static keyword on the function.